# ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_RECORD_MAC] sslv3 alert bad record mac

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, cryptography, x509

What I am trying to do is write this code that will pull down a certificate from the device and parse it out. This code works against some devices, but against others I get this error

```
PS C:\NetDevOps> & "C:/Program Files (x86)/Python38-32/python.exe" c:/NetDevOps/Cert/test6a.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/NetDevOps/Cert/test6a.py", line 17, in <module>
    pull = ssl.get_server_certificate((phoneip, 443))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1484, in get_server_certificate
    with context.wrap_socket(sock) as sslsock:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_RECORD_MAC] sslv3 alert bad record mac (_ssl.c:1108)
```

and here is my code:

```
import ssl
import OpenSSL.crypto

phonelist = ["10.129.157.30"]

for phoneip in phonelist:
    pull = ssl.get_server_certificate((phoneip, 443))
    x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, pull)

output = open(str('C:/NetDevOps/Cert/certs.txt'), 'a+')
output.write(str(phoneip) + ' Certificate' + '\n')
output.write('Issuer: ' + str(x509.get_issuer()) + '\n')
output.write('Serial Number (cert): ' + str(x509.get_serial_number()) + '\n')
output.write('Subject: ' + str(x509.get_subject()) + '\n')
output.write('Not Valid Before: ' + str(x509.get_notBefore()) + '\n')
output.write('Not Valid After: ' + str(x509.get_notAfter()) + '\n')
output.write('\n')
```

I've read a bunch of SO articles about similar related to certificate verification failing, however the above code is using the method described as a fix to that issue. Essentially pulling the cert using ssl.get_server_certificate, but then parsing the pem via OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate, but alas no luck on the failure devices, even though the code does work against some devices.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try other clients, like `openssl s_client` to see if you have the same problems. Problems can be related to how the handshake is done and what the device supports. So looking at the TLS frames can help too.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ... sslv3 alert bad record mac ...
> ```
>
> ...
>   I've read a bunch of SO articles about similar related to certificate verification failing, however the above code is using the method described as a fix to that issue.

The error you see is not related to certificate validation and thus the workarounds in this area will not work here. It is likely that the server does not correctly speak TLS in the first place or is too broken to deal with modern TLS. Some older and/or embedded systems have these problems.

It might be possible to work around such broken systems if it is known in which way they are broken. If you manage to use a browser to connect to the device one might look at the differences in the TLS handshake and try to adapt the way Python connects. If even a browser cannot connect you are likely lost.

Comment: When I connect to it via HTTPS using a web browser I get essentially the same error. When I try to connect to it via HTTP using a web browser it works fine. It is possible that it is using an older version of TLS then the web browser supports. It's not clear which TLS versions the SSL and OpenSSL.crypto packages support though. Would a TLS mismatch cause this error?

Comment: @RobertPhillips: A simple TLS mismatch would likely cause a different error. As I already said, it might be that the server does not support TLS at all or that the implementation is broken. There were several TLS stacks in the past where the authors did not actually follow the standards and made assumptions which were true for most clients at the time but which are no longer true with modern clients.

Comment: The output of the openssl s_client is here: https://pastebin.com/G97Y5SEp

It looks like the device is using TLSv1?

Comment: @RobertPhillips: It looks like that the server aborts the handshake with an error after it has send the certificate. But `get_server_certificate` needs a completed handshake, there is no way around. For me this still looks like some broken server.

Comment: is there an alternative to get_server_certificate to pull the cert without a completed handshake (like I can do from a web browser)?

Comment: You can add `-msg`  to `openssl s_client` to clearly see the frames exchanged. You can look at the code of `get_server_certificate` to see if there is a way to copy it but not depend on a complete handshake. However, all this energy would be probably better spent in trying to fix the server instead.